# Selecting item from ListView (ListView is showing database) and deleting it from list and from database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I think I found reason/or one of reasons why item from listview which is selected won't delete itself from database. When creating database rows, each row get's ID, and each time it's ID+1 for new row.
I'll tell the problem using example:

I have 5 rows in my database (5 employes), and each employe got ID automatically when it's added to database. So I have ID's 1,2,3,4,5. When I delete first row(ID=1), I have 4 rows left- 2,3,4,5, and they don't "refactor" themselves to be 1,2,3,4. So using "long id" parameter from "onItemClick" method doesn't work since I get ID=0 for clicking on first employe in list, but THAT SAME first employe in my database doesn't have ID=0, but ID=2 since I deleted employe with ID=1 before. With clicking on second employe in list, I get ID=1, and second employe in database has ID=3.

### Is there any way to make database to always use ID's from 1 to -n employes, meaning if I delete employe with ID=1 from example, is there any way to make database to change ID's, so it isn't 2,3,4,5 after deleteing ID=1, but 1,2,3,4 again??

I check all other questions and answers similar to my problem, but none of it works for me.
In MainActivity when clicked on button it switches to second activity and second layout. In that second activity I use adapter to show database list. My list is there, but I can't click on any item and delete it. I tried listeners, listActivity, etc. but nothing works. I'm still learning so please have patience.

What I want is to show this list in layout, and when user clicks on one of items, he is asked if he wants to delete, and if he chosse yes, selected item is deleted from listview and from database.

My second activity is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.List;

public class RemoveEmploye extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.del_layout);
        final Database db=new Database(this);
        final ListView lv =    (ListView)findViewById(R.id.delEmployeList);
        List<Employe> employes = db.selectAll();
        ArrayAdapter<Employe> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>
(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, employes);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void goBack(View v) {
        Intent in= new Intent(RemoveEmploye.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }
```

My second layout is (del_layout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.EmDatabase.RemoveEmploye">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="527dp"
        android:id="@+id/delEmployeList">
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/back"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="goBack"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Database selectAll() is:

```
public List<Employe> selectAll() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("EmployeDB", new String[] { ID, NAME, SURNAME, AGE,
COMPANY, WTYPE}, null, new String[] { }, null, null, null, null);
    String name="";
    String surname="";
    String age="";
    String company="";
    String wtype="";
    int id=0;
    ArrayList<Employe> employes =new ArrayList<Employe>();

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            id= Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
            name= cursor.getString(1);
            surname= cursor.getString(2);
            age= cursor.getString(3);
            company= cursor.getString(4);
            wtype= cursor.getString(5);
            Employe e= new Employe();
            e.setId(id);
            e.setName(name);
            e.setSurname(surname);
            e.setAge(Integer.parseInt(age));
            e.setCompany(company);
            e.setWorktype(wtype);
            employes.add(e);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return employes;
}
```

Comment: please provide a xml of your list item

Comment: Malik, I provided del_layout.xml file which I use to show listview, its named in my message as Second_layout

Comment: ah, no. now i see... you use a android listViewItem. you have to make you own listViewItem layout and then you can use my awnser

Comment: for further information look [here](http://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial) or search for custom listview on google

Comment: Malik, I checked on google and on site You sent me. I found only examples without database, with much more options that I understand with my knowledge at the moment. As I said already, I'm still learning, and this is my first "bigger" app project. I wonder if You could make custom listView which I need? Sorry for asking for Your time, but I'm really stuck with this, and I need to finish this assignment as soon as possible.

Comment: yeah. i think i'll send you some sample code tomorrow...

Comment: Thank You alot. One more question please. You mentioned TextView in your code below. If I understood correct, when list is clicked, ID from item that is clicked is written to that TextView, and than from TextView you get ID and use it in deleteEmployee method as parameter?
If I'm right, how can I set ID from selected item to be written to TextView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply a setOnItemClickListener to the ListView

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
```

And inside you can do whatever you want with the element. If you want to delete it you can do something like:

```
adapter.remove(position);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And your element should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

For you to select an entry of that list you have to add an OnItemClickListener like this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView employeeID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.employeeID);
        deleteEmployee(Integer.parseInt(employeeID.getText().toString()));

        adapter.remove(position);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

After that you can make you SQL query like this:

```
public void deleteEmployee(Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM EmployeDB WHERE id = " + id.toString());
    db.close();
}
```

But to get all this to work, you have to get the id of the employee in the DB
which I assume you did/will do through putting it in the list (you could hide hide the textview with `android:visibility="gone"`)

When the user now clicks on an Item the id will be read out and passed as an argument to the `deleteEmployee()` function

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in several steps.

1. make the local varible a field of the class

   ```
   private List<Employe> employes;
   ```

   in the onCreate method:

   ```
   employes = db.selectAll();
   ```
2. implement a Itemlistener

   ```
   public class RemoveEmploye extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
   ```

   in the onCreate method:

   ```
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
   ```

   overide OnItemClick method:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   }
   ```
3. In the onItemClick method, delete Listposition position in employes, save it in  the database and refresh the listview

Answer (score 0):

So.

> At first we have to use a `custom list view adapter`...

```
class delListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Employe> {

    private List<Employe> list;

    delListAdapter(List<Employe> list) {
        super(getActivity(), R.layout.delListItem, delEmployeList);
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.delListItem, parent, false);
        }

        Employe current = list.get(pos);

        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.employeeName);
        title.setText(current.getName() + ", " + current.getSurname());

        TextView id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.seriesId);
        id.setText(current.getId().toString());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list != null ? list.size() : 0;
    }
}
```

> ...and a `custom list view item`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/employeeName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name, Surname"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/employeeId"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Quick explanation:
>  Our delListAdapter does (for now) nothing more
>   than mapping a list, we give him when we call

```
    ArrayAdapter<Employe> adapter = new delListAdapter(employes);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in our onCreate function, onto the layout we've provided him.

With these lines:

```
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.employeeName);
    title.setText(current.getName() + ", " + current.getSurname());

    TextView id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.employeeId);
    id.setText(current.getId().toString());
```

we map the single elements of our list onto the visible list items.

> Now we can set our OnClickLister

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView employeeID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.employeeID);
        //TODO: make function to delete from DB

        parent.remove(position);
        parent.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

This will read out the specific id of the employee to delete him/her from the database, and also will remove the entry from the visible list.

Answer (score 0):

Malik, while waiting for your answer I tried other way. But when I click on button REMOVE app crashes. If You, or anyone know reason for crashing, please tell.
Here is the way I tried to do it:

```
public class RemoveEmploye extends Activity {
ListView lv;
int i;
Database db;
ArrayAdapter<Employe> adapter;
Employe e;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.row_view);
db = new Database(this);
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
List<Employe> employes = db.selectAll();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
android.R.id.text1, employes);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long
id) {
e = (Employe) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
i = e.getId();
System.out.println(i);
}
});
}
public void onDeleteClick() {
db.deleteEmployee(i);
adapter.remove(e);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
Intent in = new Intent(RemoveEmploye.this,RemoveEmploye.class);
startActivity(in);
}
```

Also I tried Your code, but when creating class delListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter, I get error in creating window when I write ArrayAdapter as superclass. How to avoid that?